# Tensor algebra identities

Tags: vectors, tensors

There's a bunch of very useful identities in vector algebra. For example:
$$
\boldsymbol{A}\cdot (\boldsymbol{B}\times\boldsymbol{C})=\boldsymbol{C}\cdot (\boldsymbol{A}\times\boldsymbol{B}),
$$
or:
$$
\nabla\times (f\boldsymbol{A})=(\nabla f)\times\boldsymbol{A}+f(\nabla\times\boldsymbol{A}).
$$
However, I struggle to find any decent source of such identities regarding tensors. You can easily find some like:
$$
\nabla\cdot (\boldsymbol{A}\otimes\boldsymbol{B})=(\boldsymbol{A}\cdot\nabla)\boldsymbol{B}+\boldsymbol{B}(\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol{A}),
$$
but that is because the end product is a vector. Anyone knows of a good source with such tensor algebra identities? Something that would perhaps involve such expressions? (among others needed):
$$
(\boldsymbol{A}\times\boldsymbol{B})\otimes\boldsymbol{C},
$$
or
$$
\boldsymbol{A}\times (\boldsymbol{B}\cdot\textbf{C}),
$$
where $\textbf{C}$ is a rank two tensor.

EDIT:
Actually, I would also be keen to get an extensive reference on vector identities. For example, is there an identity for:
$$
\boldsymbol{A}\times[(\boldsymbol{B}\cdot\nabla)\boldsymbol{C}]?
$$
I tried doing it myself, but I am not 100% sure of what I am allowed to do. In any case, an extensive reference for both vector and tensor identities would be much appreciated, as I don't necessarily know in advance which identities could be useful, so proving them myself is not enough.

Comment: $\boldsymbol{A}\times (\boldsymbol{B}\cdot\textbf{C}).$ is a vector crossed with a scalar?

Comment: After playing around with some of these I can't find any nice identities.

Comment: @DavidP The $\textbf{C}$ is a rank two tensor. I should have written that.

Comment: @K.defaoite I think I found something for the last one (not 100% sure): $\boldsymbol{A}\times[(\boldsymbol{B}\cdot\nabla)\boldsymbol{C}]=(\boldsymbol{B}\cdot\nabla)(\boldsymbol{A}\times\boldsymbol{C})-[(\boldsymbol{B}\cdot\nabla)\boldsymbol{A}]\times\boldsymbol{C}$

Comment: I recommend that you write all these expressions in index notation. It is a good exercise for you to practise and proofs should not been too difficult. That also helps avoid confusion with different definitions (a matrix has two indices, which one is contracted?).

Comment: @Dog_69 That's what I usually do, and have done for the above comment. As I mentioned in my question, what I want is a resource. When working out a problem, you never know in advance what identity could be useful, precisely because you don't know them in the first place. What I tried doing, is looking at bits of equations where I wondered: "can I rewrite this differently" and came up with the above identity for example. But clearly, it can take ages until you figure out by yourself which identities you actually need. That's why books usually have appendices of the most useful ones.

Comment: There might be a physics book about gravity including some identities, but I cannot remember now its name. I'm not sure anyway. But I think General Relativity books are you best chance.

Comment: Usually, the divergence of a contravariant (1,0)-tensor,  $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}$, is $A^j_{|j}$, but the expression $\nabla \cdot (A\otimes B)$ is not well defined. Possible interpretations include $(A^jB^k)_{|j}$ and $(A^jB^k)_{|k}$

Comment: @ContraKinta Really? That's a term that appears in the conservative form of the Navier-Stokes equation

Comment: Well, in continuum mechanics they don't care much about contra- and covariance and by convention they usually contract over the first index, raising it if necessary. Like this $T_{jk}=A_jB_k$ and $\nabla \cdot T$ is considered $g^{jm}T_{jk|m}=T^{m}_{\,\,\,\,k|m}$  ($=\frac{\partial T^m_k}{\partial x^m}+\Gamma^{\,\,\,m}_{r\,\,\,m}T^r_k-\Gamma^r_{km}T^m_r$)

Comment: Yeah, I haven't done general relativity in ages, and so this kind of notation is not useful to me (I'm also quite rusty). I suppose I mean I am interested in identities with the kind of second-rank tensors one usually sees in continuum mechanics and the likes.